# AWS DynamoDB FilterExpression converting attribute to String and compare with integer

Tags: python, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

AWS DynamoDB: How do I convert an attribute value to int and compare it in a python script

Example

```
fe = Attr('Colum1').eq('Value') & int(Attr('StringField')) > 3)
response = userDevices.scan(Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',FilterExpression=fe,
                                 TotalSegments=total_segment, Segment=segment)
```

While running this I am getting an error
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object, or a number, not 'Attr'
Has anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: Doubt that approach is going to work. Try `Attr('StringField').gt(3)` in case DynamoDB will coerce the string value to a numeric (not sure if it will, but worth trying).

Comment: @jarmod yes looks like it works - thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works good. Attr is part of condition, it's not result

```
fe = Attr('Colum1').eq('Value') & Attr('StringField').gt(3))
response = userDevices.scan(Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',FilterExpression=fe,
                             TotalSegments=total_segment, Segment=segment)
```